# IDF and CO versions of Sellar in OpenMDAO 1.7.3

Tags: openmdao

Does anyone have the IDF and CO versions of the Sellar Problem compatible with OpenMDAO 1.7.3? I could only find the MDF and SAND versions in the "examples" directory of the Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled with this issue, and came to the conclusion that the SubProblem component provides the basis for the IDF and CO MDAO architectures.  I have implemented the CO in this way with legacy codes each representing a discipline.  An additional benefit of this implementation is the ability to modularize the disciplines to quickly configure a problem with as-needed disciplines with little new effort.  Note: do not confuse subgroups with subproblems as the two are entirely unrelated but likely both employed within a problem.  The subproblem architecture as implemented in my project does require initializing guesses for each subproblem to converge while the SAND might not.  Modularity is more beneficial than full automation in my project.  I can envision passing control information down through the problem-subproblem-subsubproblem hierarchy to automate the configuration and perhaps the component "state" can be subverted to that use?  Hope this stimulates your imagination to complete your project.